# I2C Not Being Detected After Running Code For HMC6343

Tags: i2c

Found a code for finding heading for HMC6343 compass on the raspberry pi 3 Model B.

This is a freshly installed raspbian, I connected the device and checked with i2c tools that it's being detected and it was.

Then I installed [bcm2835  1.70](https://www.airspayce.com/mikem/bcm2835/) and used make to build the files from [github repository](https://github.com/awerries/lowcost-sensors/tree/master/Cpp_Tools) I found for the compass.

Once I run the code, I get "Sensor Initialization Failed". If I run the i2c detect again, it doesn't see the sensor. However, if I unplug it and plug it back in, then it will see it until I run the code again.

Not really sure where the issue is. I even tried connecting the sensor directly to the pi without a breadboard since I saw someone having a similar issue and that was their solution.